# Look for popen output changes

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I need to create a program that does this:

- execute a command with popen
- do things with the output of popen(use the FILE in a lot of things)
- stay checking for popen output changes, if have one, re execute everything.

The source code is here: https://gitorious.org/clyv/clyv

So I only want to execute all the rest of the program AGAIN if there is a change in the output of popen (must be compared with the first output)
The program should do everything first time, and after, only do everything and print again if there is a change on popen output. The popen should verified once a second.

## Update

I didn't get any answer that solve my problem here, but reading a C tutorial i saw something about threads, and it sounds like the solution to me, i will see what i can do.

Comment: A probably simpler and definitely more streamlined way to do this would be to read `/proc/meminfo`, extract the value from the second line ("MemFree") with `sscanf()` or `fscanf()` and divide by 1024.  That's where `free` gets its numbers from.

Comment: This command is only a example, and in this example i can get the value by reading a file. But suppose that i can't.

Comment: Your scenario is not clear to me. It seems that you want to run a command (sample only in the question), and both record the exact contents of the output and do processing based on the output before it's done. Further, at some time after reading all the data from the first invocation, you want to launch a new copy of the command, read the data again, processing information as you go, and also noting whether the new contents is the same as the old. If that's what you're after, what is the delay between iterations? Should the processing on the second time occur even with no change in the output?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Edited again, see if you understand

Comment: OK.  So, on the second (or any subsequent) iteration, it must read all the output from the command, compare that with what it got before, and redo the actions if there's a difference on the current iteration.  Is it OK to do the actions after the data is all read on the first iteration (and if not, why not, because it will be a whole heap easier to manage "read all the output from the command" and "if anything is different, process the output from this iteration").

Answer (score 1):

You are free to call `popen()` as many times as needed. But, to properly release resources used by a call to `popen()`, you need to call `pclose()`.

In your case, you probably want to just poll the output occasionally, and emit something whenever it is necessary to do so.

```
first_time = 1;
need_to_print = 1;
for (;;) {
    FILE *fp = popen(...);
    /* read input ... */
    pclose(fp);
    /* parse input ... */
    if (first_time) {
        /* save contents for future comparison... */
        first_time = 0;
    } else {
        need_to_print = /* result of comparing saved contents with new contents */;
    }
    if (need_to_print) {
        /* print something ... */
    }
    sleep(INTERVAL);
}
```

Comment: But if I use the FILE in a lot of things during all the rest of the program, do you thing it's a good idea put all the rest of program in the loop?

Comment: The `read input ...` comment means to read all the input into a buffer. Then close the `fp` with `pclose()`. After that, use the buffer for the things you need. You don't need to hang on to the FILE.

Comment: @HenriqueLengler: Your update is unclear. You say you only want to execute the command again if the output is different from the first execution. But, how do you know that something has changed unless you actually execute it again? I think you are confused about your requirements. Can you clarify again, perhaps with a real example of a problem that actually needs to be solved the way you describe it?

Comment: @jhk No, i mean execute the popen command everytime but only execute the rest if there is a change. As i say here "So I only want to execute -all the rest- of the program AGAIN if there is a change in the output of popen"

Comment: @jhx what for(;;) does?

Comment: @HenriqueLengler: Same as `while (1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
    //an array of 2 string buffers
    char output[2][1024];
    //the string buffer index in use
    int flip = 0;
    FILE *fp;

```
void executeTestCommand() {


    int resultSize;
    fp = popen("free -m | awk 'NR==3 {print $3}'" "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to run command");
    }
    else {
        result_size = fread(output, 1, 1024 - 1, fp);
        //place string terminator
        output[flip][result_size] = '\0';
    }
    //flip the buffers
    flip = flip ^ 1;
    pclose(fp);
}


int main() {
    //init with empty string
    output[0][0] = '\0';
    output[1][0] = '\0';
    //for ever
    for(;;) {
        executeTestCommand();
        //if the last command output differs from the current
        //command output
        if (strcmp(output[0], output[1])) {
            //execute the rest of the command here
        }           
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Cheers!

You want to close the file pointer (you don't want any memory leaks) since you are going to use the same FILE * fp variable again with popen.

Later edit: hope it helps:). You might want to insert a sleep statement inside the for ever block because this will be cpu intensive.

Comment: I can only comment here, so you want to execute the rest only if `cmus-remote -Q` returns something different from the last time?

Comment: Exactly this. I wanna look every second for a change in the command output, if there is a change, re execute the other commands.

Answer (score 0):

@AlinUngureanu @JonathanLeffler @jxh

I published the source on git! Now you can see what i want

https://gitorious.org/clyv/clyv

Comment: While it may be helpful to make the full source available, it is generally a **bad** idea to refer people to external sources for purposes of your question. Posts are expected to have a concise question, all relevant code in the post, if appropriate your compile string showing the build flags, requested warning and libraries used, as well as any related error messages, along with necessary sample input and output. You will get more help that way.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's horrible to paste code here, i need to de 4 whitespace before any line of code.

Comment: I agree with you. An easy way to prepare the code for posting (if your editor won't do it automatically) is simply to use `sed`. It works with any text file. Just: `sed -e 's/^/    /' < filename` Of course you can redirect that to a temp file to open in your editor as well: `sed -e 's/^/    /' < filename > tempfile`  HTH (that is **4-spaces** in the second part of the `sed` command.)